# What is an Operating System which runs on a Raspberry Pi and is GNU-free software supported?

Tags: open-source, raspberry-pi, operating-system, debian

I'm looking at this list of fully GNU-backed operating systems

https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.en.html

And cross-referencing them with this list of Raspberry Pi supported operating systems

https://www.techrepublic.com/pictures/choosing-a-raspberry-pi-os-heres-the-definitive-list/

And I'm not coming up with any cross-matches like I was hoping.

I'm planning on running a Raspberry Pi 4B with 8GB of ram, and I'm looking for some help.

To be clear, I don't just mean "free" or "open-source" but GNU-supported. It's possible though that neither list is fully comprehensive, and so I'm hoping to get some help here. If it's not possible though then I'm asking for the next closest thing in terms of free and open ecosystems, preferably Debian-based.

Comment: Does this site provide any help? https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.en.html

Comment: I think the pi uses some binary blobs for the GPU - that means that you cannot have both full Pi support and full GNU backing.

Comment: @shortmanikos thank you for clearing that up, I was not aware.

Comment: After a quick research, it turns out that the GPU is not the only problem, wifi and USB also depend on non-free blobs (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=285875)